# MySQL Between Command Returning Wrong Ip Adress or Numbers

Tags: mysql, ip, return, between

I've a MySQL tables which inlude ip addresses like "192.168.1.1" etc., i want to get ip addresses between 1.20 and .136, ip column type is varchar and my query is ;

```
select * from kayitlar where ip between ('192.168.1.20') and ('192.168.1.36')
```

When i run this command, mysql return records between 1.20 and 1.36, and also it return records like 1.220,.1.224 etc. i also tryed to do with <= or >= operators but result was the same.

What am i missing here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'INET_ATON'` function on IPV4 type of addresses.

```
SELECT * from kayitlar 
 WHERE   INET_ATON( ip ) BETWEEN 
         INET_ATON( '192.168.1.20' ) 
     AND INET_ATON( '192.168.1.36' )
```

You can also try `'HEX'` on ip addresses.

```
SELECT  * FROM kayitlar 
 WHERE  HEX( ip ) BETWEEN 
        HEX( '192.168.1.20' ) 
    AND HEX( '192.168.1.36' )
  FROM  kayitlar
```

**Refer to**:

- [**MySQL:  INET_ATON( expr )**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)

  - Return the numeric value of an IP address

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do more complex matching against the IP addresses, I'd suggest you use `int` data type for storing the IP addresses. MySQL supports `inet_aton()`/`inet_ntoa()` for conversion between dotted notation and `int`.

If you do that, then you can use the following, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM kayitlar 
 WHERE ip BETWEEN INET_ATON('192.168.1.20') AND INET_ATON('192.168.1.36');
```

This will also allow you to perform subnet matching using bitwise operators:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(INET_ATON('192.168.0.1') & INET_ATON('255.255.255.0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query:

```
select * from kayitlar where SUBSTRING(ip, 9) between ('1.20') and ('1.36');
```